# How do I solve an error code 127 when doing a pg_dumpall through a cronjob?

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have this simple script to backup all my databases in postgres

```
    pg_dumpall -U pg_user > /tmp/tmp.txt
    DUMP_STATUS=$?
    echo "Dump status: $DUMP_STATUS" > /tmp/status.txt
```

The dump status is 0 and the tmp.txt file is properly created when the script is executed from the command line.

However, if I execute this script as a cronjob in my crontab, my tmp.txt is empty (the dump of all databases failed) and my status.txt file contains a dump status 127.

A strange behavior I noticed is that pg_dumpall will pipe the information into the file but also print it on the terminal.  I'm thinking this behavior might be the cause of the problem.

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

I am running FreeBSD:

```
    > uname -mrs  
    FreeBSD 9.1-PRERELEASE amd64

    > psql -V
    psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.7
    contains support for command-line editing
```

Comment: A few points: 1) you should chdir to a usefull directory or hardcode all filepaths in a cronjob. 2) PATH can be different than for a login shell. 3) the script can (and should) redirect stderr (possibly separately from stdout). 4) always start with a dummy cronjob, eg echo and date, psql select version() etc. That will get you on track wrt to path/environment errors. 5) use (or redirect) MAILTO=

Comment: Normally, 127 [means](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) "command not found", so I'm with @wildplasser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script can work apart from a crontab, you should make sure of the following:

- The script file contains the necessary environmental variables

  - `$PGHOME`
  - `$PGDATA`
  - `$PGPORT`
  - `$PATH`
- Output the standard error to a file for future analysis

Answer (score 2):

According to http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html a 127 code means "command not found."

As *francs* suggested, when you run the command normally you are implicitly relying on one or more environmental variables that exist for your login shell, but which do not exist when you run a cron job.  The solution is to give absolute paths to every command.

For example, type "which pg_dumpall" in the terminal and use the resulting output where you currently have "pg_dumpall" in your scripts.

Comment: You guys are right. The proper environment variables were not set when the script is executed as a cronjob. This was really a silly mistake.  
  
On bash execution:  
`PATH: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin`  
On crontab execution:  
`PATH: /usr/bin:/bin`  
  
So the correction was this:  
`-pg_dumpall -U pg_user > /tmp/tmp.txt`  
`+/usr/local/bin/pg_dumpall -U $PG_USER > /tmp/tmp.txt`  
  
This works marvelously afterwards :)